# ABCpdf 5 Problems with encoding (special characters)

Tags: c#, asp.net, abcpdf

I am using ABCpdf Version 5 in order to render some html-pages into PDFs.

I basically use `HttpServerUtility.Execute()` - Method in order to retrieve the html for the pdf:

```
System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
server.Execute(requestUrl, writer);
string pageResult = writer.ToString();

WebSupergoo.ABCpdf5.Doc pdfDoc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf5.Doc();
pdfDoc.AddImageHtml(pageResult);

response.Buffer = false;
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=MyPdf_" + 
    FormatDate(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd") + ".pdf");
response.BinaryWrite(pdfDoc.GetData());
```

Now *some* special characters like Umlaute (äöü) are replaced with an empty space. Interestingly not all of them. What I did figure out:
Within the html-page I have.

```
`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8" />`
```

If I parse this away, all special chars are rendered correctly. But this seems to me like an ugly hack.

In earlier days I did not use `HttpServerUtility.Execute()`, but I let ABCpdf call the URL itself: `pdfDoc.AddImageUrl("someUrl");`. There I had no such encoding-problems.

What could I try else?

Comment: I realized that ABCpdf Verion 7 doesn't seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Just came across this problem with [ABCpdf 8](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/encoding-issues-with-abcpdf8/).

In your code you retrieve HTML contents and pass the pageResult to AddImageHtml(). As the [documentation](http://websupergoo.com/helppdf5/default.html?page=source/5-object_reference/doc/1-methods/addimagehtml.htm) states,

> ABCpdf saves this HTML into a temporary file and renders the file
>   using a 'file://' protocol specifier.

What is not mentioned is that the temp file is UTF-8 encoded, but the encoding is not stated in the HTML file.

The <meta> tag  actually sets the required encoding, and solved my problem.

One way to avoid the declaration of the encoding is to use the [AddImageUrl()](http://websupergoo.com/helppdf5/source/5-object_reference/doc/1-methods/addimageurl.htm) method that I expect to detect the HTML encoding from the HTTP/HTML response.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding meta tag and AddImageURL method perhaps helps with simple document, but not in a chain situation, where encoding somehow gets lost despite encoding tag. I encountered this problem (exactly as described in original question - some foreign characters such as umlauts would disappear), and see no solution. I am considering getting rid of ABCPDF altogether and replace it with SSRS, which can render PDF formats.