# ABCpdf ellipsis and apostrophes showing up garbled

Tags: special-characters, ellipsis, apostrophe, abcpdf

In my situation, users are able to insert their own text into a field before printing the page as a pdf. Some of these users have been copying and pasting from Word, so the special apostrophes and ellipsis characters are being saved in the field. These special characters are fine when viewing the html page but render as a garbled mess when ABCpdf gets a hold of them.

I have tried adding the following to the head of the page as per [ABCpdf 5 Problems with encoding (special characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678936/abcpdf-5-problems-with-encoding-special-characters)

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8" />
```

I have also tried this: [Symbol font on ABCpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521215/symbol-font-on-abcpdf)

```
theDoc.HtmlOptions.FontEmbed = true;
theDoc.HtmlOptions.FontSubstitute = false;
theDoc.HtmlOptions.FontProtection = false;
```

I'm using the method AddImageUrl() for the rendering.

How do I make these special characters show up properly using ABCpdf?